# LANDSAT 8 Road Extraction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, classification, ecognition

I have 80 LANDSAT 8 Images. I can able to create composite image using Arcgis and then Pansharpen it to produce 15m multi-spectral image as a input for classification process. **My requirement is to extract only roads vector(Polygon) data from LANDSAT 8 Images** using ecognition developer.
After segmentation, I have tried NDVI,NDWI ruleset in eCognition to unclassify vegetation and water areas(so that I can get road) but it doesn't seem possible to classify road data completely.

Is there any specific ruleset available for extracting roads?

I have licensed Arcgis 10.2.1, Ecognition developer 9 as of now.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb using multi-spectral images with more than 30% more spatial extent than Pan image will lead to serious case of mixed pixels. This should be avoided at all cost. As is your case, this value is 50%.As such i suggest you increase resolution of the multi-spectral images. Also Landsat itself are a mid resolution images, I don't expect you to get road network of all classes. Maybe highways with 4 lanes or greater will be easily classified but that is pushing your luck too much. Best case would be to digitize it yourself.

Comment: I agree. Switching to S-2A/S-2B could be an alternative for this purpose.

Comment: @overarch Yeah! Can you guide me how to extract primary roads from LANDSAT 8 scenes?

Comment: @Gis_Boy you can publish your results here then we can help you. Can't hand hold you through the entire exercise.

Comment: I have tried in eCognition and got primary roads only.Rulesets I have used are i) NDVI to unclassify vegetation ii) NDWI to unclassify water iii) BAI and REI to get road structures and used Density parameter also. This is what I have got! Looking for better results

Comment: @aldo_tapia I have checked S2A 10m resolution Image It gives result as same as LANDSAT

Comment: @Gis_Boy is the best resolution for free imagery. If you want better results, buy rapideye, worldview or quickbird images

Comment: @Gis_Boy instead of using eCognition, can you try classifying data with ENVI taking training set of only two groups(road and non-road) and share the results? Use the methodology in Sentinel imagery.

Comment: @OverArch I didnt try supervised classification in ENVI but I have tried it in ArcGis,Regarding to ENVI, Spectral values that we are taking in **road** group could be definitely present outside real roads.So cluster cleanup process will be required if I use ENVI.Right? (I have no idea, just asking you)

Comment: Yeah cleanup would definitely be a good idea. Also try to restrict your training set. That would help you a lot at a later stage. Better to have less roads than too many of them. By restricting I mean to say that please try not to train your road network by taking roadside trees into consideration too. Creates a nasty classified layer.

Comment: I have tried it! Since the spectral reflectance of road changes from image to image, I have to create a new training set for every Landsat scene! Is there any problem with my config or this is correct? I am using 4-3-2 bands

Comment: This config seems correct. You need to create new training sets for each scene. Or you try histogram equalization on all the raster data when you merge tem into a single scene. That may do the trick. But safer approach will be to go with individual training sets for each scene. Best would still be to get a higher resolution satellite dat though.

Answer (score 0):

you should also try textural information for extracting roads, when editing the NN feature space

Comment: I dont understand, Could you explain bit clear?